# is there any api which could provide me with the .mp3 file by taking input as song name? . I couldn't find any

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

import { Media, Player, controls } from 'react-media-player'
const { PlayPause, MuteUnmute } = controls

class MediaPlayer extends Component {
render() {
return (











)
}
}

Comment: Where do you expect the API to search the song? Amazon? Sony? YouTube? some sort of GoodReads?

Comment: i just want it to provide me with a url of the mp3 file so that i can use it to play it in my website

Comment: all i want to do is to take song name from user and play it!

Comment: Do you own the mp3 file?

Comment: no , i just want it in this form : https://nusid.net/audio.mp3

Comment: Sorry, maybe I´m missing something but it sounds like you want to be able to listen to any song in the world for free by just saying the song name...if that is what you are looking for I doubt you can get it...the closes things I know that are for "free" (you get advertisment) are YouTube, Spotify, etc...unless you are happy with a few seconds of the song...that may exists...(don´t know where though..)